# Flask : How to do server side cleanup on session expiration?

Tags: python, session, flask

I have some objects allocated and maintained server side for the duration of a session. How can I make sure that these are cleaned up after a session expires?

Is there support for this in Flask, or some Flask extension?

Comment: How are you maintaining your session server side? Have you implemented the SessionInterface in flask ?

Comment: @codegeek I don't see where / how SessionInterface can be used to clean up on session expiration. Other than implementing some periodic task that checks for expired sessions. I was asking if there is a more direct facility, like a callback on session expiration, or something.

Comment: I didn't say to use SessionInterface use to clean up what you are asking. I was asking how you have implemented your session. Are you using database, in memory, memcache, redis? Cleaning up depends on what and where to clean up. I suggest you post some sample code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're instantiating objects, not saving them anywhere, just keeping them in memory.

If this is true, then the garbage collector will take them away automatically: just clear all references to them, "forget them" if you will. If you can't access them yourself, they'll be cleaned up.

If you want to be explicit about it, then use a scheduler (maybe http://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) and create a task timed on session expiry. When the task is ran, verify the session is indeed not needed anymore, and destroy your objects.